# Dynamically setup gitlab-ci cache.key

Tags: gitlab-ci

It there a way to set up cache: key: dynamically, like this:

```
cache:
    key: if $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE -eq 'merge_request_event' { "MR_$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TRAGET_BRANCH_NAME_CACHE" } else { "PUSH_$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME_CACHE" }
```

Or maybe there is a way to define a pipile variable dynamically:

```
variables:
    CACHE_KEY: if $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE -eq 'merge_request_event' { "MR_$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TRAGET_BRANCH_NAME_CACHE" } else { "PUSH_$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME_CACHE" }                            

cache:
    key: $CACHE_KEY
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a [rules check](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesvariables), so like this:

```
  variables:
    //Your default value
    CACHE_KEY: "PUSH_$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME_CACHE"
  rules:
    - if: if $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      //Override based on the above condition 
      variables:
        CACHE_KEY: "MR_$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TRAGET_BRANCH_NAME_CACHE"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your solution because of my Gitlab instance doesn't support vars in rules. But if someone checks that it's working really and cache:key settigs really gets changed variable, I will mark you answer as accepted one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#cachekey) says:

> Possible inputs:
>
> - A string
> - A predefined variables
> - A combination of both.

As an option, you might define one "default" cache which fits best for most cases and another one for specific cases